# Heroku: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch - Python

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, bottle

I am trying to host a bottle app that uses tensorflow to heroku, the app starts and I got the **'server running on port'** as well. but the application is not opening and after a minute or so, it showing a the below trace

Opening trace saying the server is running successfully,

```
2018-08-25T19:46:55.651043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python ./api.py -p 37040`
2018-08-25T19:47:01.379243+00:00 app[web.1]: Bottle v0.12.13 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
2018-08-25T19:47:01.379274+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/
2018-08-25T19:47:01.379309+00:00 app[web.1]: Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
2018-08-25T19:47:01.379318+00:00 app[web.1]:undefined
```

After few minutes after. error trace.

```
2018-08-25T19:47:56.239318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2018-08-25T19:47:56.239392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-08-25T19:47:56.330436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-08-25T19:47:56.353021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-08-25T19:47:59.452460+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-forest-70642.herokuapp.com request_id=8b62b91c-8f22-4c37-b3c5-cbc7e8415e3d fwd="123.231.104.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-08-25T19:47:59.500660+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=boiling-forest-70642.herokuapp.com request_id=e8860f29-40fd-46b1-b9f2-96683f53d524 fwd="123.231.104.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-08-25T19:48:02.118233+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-forest-70642.herokuapp.com request_id=1f9aafbe-f410-46ab-84ed-41bbc90857e6 fwd="123.231.104.11" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I don't know what I have done wrong, since I am new to heroku or bottle.

procfile:

```
web: python ./api.py -p $PORT
```

api.py file

```
@get('/')
def get_top_predictions():
    #lable_index, labels_list, results_list = li.get_lables("bottle.jpg")
    #selected_list = [{"class": labels_list[i], "probability": float(results_list[i]) } for i in lable_index]
    #return {"predictions": selected_list}
    return {"predictions": "Hello Man"}

run()
```

Also I tried options like setting `run(host='0.0.0.0')` aswell. still it not working and giving the same error message.

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app needs to bind to the Heroku-provided port on an externally visible address. You have both ingredients, just not mixed together correctly. You tried `run(host='0.0.0.0')` and you include `-p $PORT` in the Procfile, but don't show the code indicating how you use it.

Try this instead:

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=os.environ.get('PORT', '5000'))
```

Comment: It worked, Thanks, also I have a small doubt, why the port number is 5000, is it a must to use that port number or can we give any number. Also, If I give another port number like 8000, will it map to port 80.

Comment: In the code snippet, "5000" is just a default if the environment variable is empty. Heroku assigns the port dynamically when the dyno starts, and sets it in the `PORT` variable. With the code snippet, you could run the app w/out the environment variable, and it will bind to "5000".